# Jenkins prolem to copy a build file to a windows share

Tags: plugins, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I am a newbie to Jenkins and I have finally created a successful build using Jenkins. I have installed the jenkins-CIFS publisher plugin to move this "jar"  file from the original location to another windows server(server1).

I have created the CIFS share and tested configuration successfully. As a post build step I am trying to add the option - "Send files to a window share".

The problem is I do not know how to generalize the source location of jar file.

My jar location is C:\Documents and Settings\username.jenkins\jobs\web-application\modules\com.app$drup\builds\2012-09-25_23-23-45\archive\drup.jar

As a post build step I want the latest jar (irrespective of date and time) to be moved over to the other windows server.

I also need (if possible) for jenkins to first connect to the windows server ; then rename the existing drup.jar ; and then copy the newly created drup.jar to the windows server(server1).

Can someone please provide help?

Answer (score 0):

What generates the file name?  Is it part of the build process or post build process?  You could store a link to the file or a file with the filename as the contents and then read that file to use as the location.

Basically you need to capture your filename in the build steps and then use it later.

Good luck.